# Create and import database from url

Tags: php, database, directadmin

I've script in directadmin which create new clean database:

```
#Create DB
  /usr/bin/mysqladmin -uda_admin -p$(cat /usr/local/directadmin/conf/mysql.conf | grep pass | cut -d\= -f2 ) create ${wpconfigdbuser};
  echo "CREATE USER ${wpconfigdbuser} IDENTIFIED BY '${dbpass}';" | mysql -uda_admin -p$(cat /usr/local/directadmin/conf/mysql.conf | grep pass | cut -d\= -f2 );
  echo "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ${wpconfigdbuser}.* TO ${wpconfigdbuser} IDENTIFIED BY '${dbpass}';" | mysql -uda_admin -p$(cat /usr/local/directadmin/conf/mysql.conf | grep pass | cut -d\= -f2);
```

Now I need add to above code to import sample database from URL. example: `mydomain.com/files/database.sql`

Can anyone help me implement this to code?

update:

```
#Create DB
      /usr/bin/mysqladmin -uda_admin -p$(cat /usr/local/directadmin/conf/mysql.conf | grep pass | cut -d\= -f2 ) create ${wpconfigdbuser};
      echo "CREATE USER ${wpconfigdbuser} IDENTIFIED BY '${dbpass}';" | mysql -uda_admin -p$(cat /usr/local/directadmin/conf/mysql.conf | grep pass | cut -d\= -f2 );
      echo "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ${wpconfigdbuser}.* TO ${wpconfigdbuser} IDENTIFIED BY '${dbpass}';" | mysql -uda_admin -p$(cat /usr/local/directadmin/conf/mysql.conf | grep pass | cut -d\= -f2);

#Import DB:

    exec('mysql -u '.DB_USER.' -p'.DB_PASSWORD.' '.DB_NAME.' table_name < mydomain.com/files/database.sql;');
```

Now script create database and import sql file?

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you are using wordpress

```
exec('mysql -u '.DB_USER.' -p'.DB_PASSWORD.' '.DB_NAME.' table_name < mydomain.com/files/database.sql;');
```

It'll run a shell_exec using the constants defined in wp-config.php and execute the sql in the database.sql file.

Note this won't work in shared hosting

Comment: Thanks. I check this. I have dedicated server with DA.

Comment: Could you please help us to implement to our code so that the above code is executed, i.e. database creation + import? Can you check my update?

Comment: what does your .sql file look like i.e what statements are in it INSERT, CREATE etc

Comment: this is example: https://github.com/vccw-team/repository-example-of-wp/blob/master/wordpress.sql

Comment: that would create and insert the table and replace the existing table, with the above script.  You might want to amend the .sql file so it only has the insert commands

Comment: otherwise I'm not sure how to part execute that script?